# One dropdown that displays results with an add button

Tags: jquery

How can I duplicate the "Results" span and have it gather the new set of data when the user wants to build another result? (I am terrible with jquery but will try to post the finished solution here)

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button>Add another</button>
<span class="results">Results:  </span>


document.jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("button").click(function() 
        {   
            var $newResults = $('span.results').last().clone().appendTo('span.results').html();

        });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain better, not sure what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: duplicate the span or duplicate the span content?

Comment: Sorry.  The user selects from the dropdown.  The results are appended to the "Results" span.  Then, if the user wants to build another selection they click the "Add Another" button and an empty Results span appears ready for another dropdown selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var newResultSpan = '<span class="results">Results: </span>';

$("select").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("span.results").last().append($this.val());
});

$("button").click(function() {
    $("body").append(newResultSpan);
});
```

fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/rTrJr/